# Time delay between two threads in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, sleep, wait

I have the following situation:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        method(object1);
    }
}.start();

// some code ... 

new Thread() {
    public void run() { 
        method(object2);
    }
}.start();
```

The used method is a map-drawing method. So basically, first I need to draw a map with `object1` and then after some time e.g. 5 sec another map using `object2`.

I tried to put `Thread.sleep(5000)` between two `Thread`s, also after and so on... But I couldn't make it work. Any suggestions?

In this case object 2 is displayed and the object 1 is not! 
 If I comment the second thread, the first object is drawn. Also if I comment the first thread the second object is drawn. 

The thing I need is to present object1 for 10 seconds and then to present object2.

Comment: Please provide a clearer overview of what you are trying to do and what you have done. Where did you actually put the `sleep` calls? What else is running?

Comment: It seems you want them to execute one after another... in that case, why are you using threads? If you explain what you are trying to achieve, that will help us help you. For the time being, any kind of synchronising between threads will require sync blocks and locks, but I do not know if that's what you want.

Comment: show us what you tried. Thread.sleep() makes the current thread sleep. You must have made a mistake.

Comment: If by drawing, you mean draw in some Swing component, then all the drawing should be done in the EDT.

Answer (score 4):

Try making it easier:

```
method(object1);
Thread.sleep(5000);
method(object2);
```

There's no need to run threads if you need to wait for 5 seconds.

Alternatively, you can use `java.util.Timer`—but so far it seems your problem is not in the delay part.

Comment: If I do like that only the second map becomes visible! It seems like the first call to method is not invoked.

Comment: @ilija be sure that the first call _is indeed invoked._ What may happen is one of the follows: (1) it may fail to call `invalidate()` or `repaint()` on UI; (2) it may fail to actually update the ui. Try only call the first method, and check that you can actually see the results.

Comment: The "sleep()" is a definite "yellow flag" indicating potential design error.  "sleep()" should be used ONLY as a "last resort".  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 it depends on the problem we solve. if the problem is, *`object1` is not getting drawn,* then `sleep()` is _not_ a problem, and thus should be left as is until the real problem is solved. I do agree that a proper scheduler, be it a `Timer` or an `ExecutorService`, is The Way—but until we solve a problem, it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: repaint is working fine. so if i comment the second method call the object1 is drawn. the same is vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to draw the map with object2 after object1, you should do

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        method(object1);
        method(object2);
    }
}.start();
```

I am not sure how long your method(object1) takes to run but if this takes more than 5 seconds and the thread comes back after the sleep, method(object2) will start and it is possible to the method(object2) will be done first if this take less time than method(object1).

Comment: I like your solution better than mine :)

Comment: In this case only the second map which corresponds to method(object2) is drawn. The first one is not.